# Cardlist is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I made cardList and want to add card into cardlist through map but this error appears

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';

const Cardlist = ({robots})=>{
    const cardComponent = robots.map((user,i) => {
       return <Card name = {robots[i].name} id ={robots[i].id} email = {robots[i].email} />
    })
    return (
      <div>
        {cardComponent}
      </div>
    );
}

export default CardList;
```

Comment: What is your error? What is the parent component?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting Cardlist is not defined because you didn't export it properly.

```
export default CardList;
```

should become

```
export default Cardlist;
```

Comment: Good catch @Ido, +1.

Comment: That was the problem actually...thanks for clearing

Comment: What's different between these lines? Those are the same!

Comment: @AmirAstaneh they are not the same. Cardlist vs CardList. One has upper case L, and the other does not have.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your component with name `Cardlist` and exported with `CardList`, a typo here. Your export should be this,

```
export default Cardlist
```

Also, by the time your component mounts, your `robots` array might not contain data and it fails.

You should always check if data present,

```
const cardComponent = robots && robots.length && robots.map((user,i) => {
    return <Card name = {robots[i].name} id ={robots[i].id} email = {robots[i].email} />
})
```

**Note:** If you already iterating over array and taking each element into `user` then you can directly use `user` to get data.

```
const cardComponent = robots && robots.length && robots.map((user,i) => {
    return <Card name = {user.name} id ={user.id} email = {user.email} />
})
```